# Randomized Match Finding

Tags: random, array-difference

Say I have two files or arrays, type doesn't matter, with a size of 184x184. I try to find out if these items are different with a code like below:

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    x = r.nextInt(184);
    y = r.nextInt(184);
    if(item1[x,y] != item2[x,y]) {
        break;
    }
}
```

My question is, what should the value of *N* be? Should I run tests, is there a defacto rate between *N* and the *size*?

Comment: It is going to depend on how confident you want to be and the contents of the files. Can you be specific about either, or is it a general question?

Comment: I do a two layered comparison: first do this randomized non-match finding, if it succeeds, I do a index-by-index comparison for all indexes of two arrays.

Comment: Out of interest, do you have any evidence that this 'pre-filter' would reject better than index-by-index with early out? This is why I asked about the content. Without further evidence, my answer to your question is probably N = 0 is best. I am ready to be proved wrong :)

Comment: I compare product images, in general the photos include products in center, background is generally one coloured, most commonly white. Also pictures could have frames. Also, after the randomized, while doing pixel by pixel comparison, I compare images' central square block first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the program gets out of the loop when it finds differents values for the same index:

- It's OK to give N a big number, the loop won't tire the computer as the loop will be broken in at most 10th-20th step.

As differences will be found in very low values of "i":

- There's no need for bigger values of N.

So according to my experimentations, defacto value for N is 20. For similar or background is dominant in the pictures the value can be increased up to 100.